# Unable to create new Database in Openerp

Tags: postgresql, odoo, openerp-7

From the line Manage Database i'm trying to create a new database.I'm getting the follwoing error.Please help me.Thank's in advance

Error:

```
client Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/addons/web/http.py", line 204, in dispatch
    response["result"] = method(self, **self.params)
  File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 777, in create
    params['create_admin_pwd'])
  File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/addons/web/session.py", line 30, in proxy_method
    result = self.session.send(self.service_name, method, *args)
  File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/addons/web/session.py", line 103, in send
    raise xmlrpclib.Fault(openerp.tools.ustr(e), formatted_info)


Server Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/addons/web/session.py", line 89, in send
    return openerp.netsvc.dispatch_rpc(service_name, method, args)
  File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/netsvc.py", line 292, in dispatch_rpc
    result = ExportService.getService(service_name).dispatch(method, params)
  File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/service/web_services.py", line 122, in dispatch
    return fn(*params)
  File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/service/web_services.py", line 168, in exp_create_database
    _initialize_db(self, id, db_name, demo, lang, user_password)
  File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/service/web_services.py", line 98, in _initialize_db
    cr.close()
  File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/sql_db.py", line 160, in wrapper
    raise psycopg2.OperationalError(msg)
OperationalError: Unable to use a closed cursor.
```

Answer (score 0):

I have modified the base module.So when it is creating a new database it is finding the changes so we cann't create a new Database.So I had edited my changes back and I successfully created the new Database.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I solved it by changing my module.

In my file __openerp__.py, I removed the line :

> "active": True,

and it work fine!